# Basic Animation With Arrow Keys

Tags: java, processing

My goal is to cycle the character from:

```
0-3 when DOWN key is pressed |
4-7 when LEFT key is pressed |
8-11 when RIGHT key is pressed |
12-15 when UP key is pressed |
```

My program is responding with the arrow key now especially with "DOWN key" but it starts looping from [0] every time it finishes the entire loop. What could I possibly do to fix this?

[image: Ash's Sprite]

```
PImage[] p = new PImage[16];
int frameCounter = 0;
int current;
int walkTo = 15;
int walkFrom;

void setup(){
frameRate(60);
size(200,200);
imageMode(CENTER);
ashWalk();
}

void draw() {
background(255);
image(p[current], width/2, height/2);
if(frameCounter % 8 == 0) { 
  if (current > walkTo-1)current = walkFrom;
  current++;
}
  frameCounter++;
}

void ashWalk(){
 for(int i = 0; i < walkTo+1; i++){
  p[i] = loadImage("Pokemon"+i+".png");
  } 
}

void keyPressed() {
ashWalk();
if (key == CODED) {
  if (keyCode == DOWN){
    walkFrom = 0;
    walkTo = 3;
  }  
  else if(keyCode == LEFT){
    walkFrom = 4; //what I would possibly want is to start looping in this number
    walkTo = 7;
  }
  else if(keyCode == RIGHT){
    walkFrom = 8;
    walkTo = 11;
  }
  else if(keyCode == UP){
    walkFrom = 12;
    walkTo = 15;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: have you checked [here](https://processing.org/reference/keyCode.html)?

Comment: Thank you! I am going to give this a try.

Comment: Are you a student? If so, can you use class or OOP if this is school related?

Comment: I have edited my question. Hopefully, somebody could give me a clue to the solution.

Comment: I would like to suggest to add a new variable `walkFrom` and let `current` loop from `walkFrom` to `walkTo`. Now you reset current to 0 but maybe you were walking RIGHT so it had to loop from 8. Why do you increase `current` in  keyPressed. Doing it in draw is not enough ?

Comment: @Conffusion that works! Thanks! actually, I have deleted that current++ inside the keyPressed() that was a mistake. my program is now looping with walkFrom to walkTo. I just have a bug now that the character still starts at 0 AT FIRST even UP key is press but then walks from 12-15 eventually. what I would want is to start from 12 immediately after the UP key is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding `ashWalk` is responsible for initialising the image array[0-15].
So I don't see a need to call it each time in `keyPressed`.

In `draw` you have to verify if current is still in the range of [walkFrom-walkTo].
If not (this can be the case when walkFrom-walkTo is updated by a keypress) you have to reset current with walkFrom:

```
if (current >= walkTo || current < walkFrom)
    current = walkFrom;
else
    current++;
```

if you calculate this before you draw the current image, current is always within the correct range.